# Visual Studio Load Test "No such host is known"

Tags: visual-studio, network-programming, load-testing

I am trying to load test with Visual Studio. I have the test on my local machine, the controller set up on a Server (WinServer 2008 R2) and the Agents on a separate server (WinServer 2008 R2).

I have successfully setup the test controller in visual studio and can connect to it (when i open up Manage test controller, enter in the controller server address, I can find it, and the related agents show up as well)

But when I try to run the test, it throws the error:

> Test run 'TestName' could not be executed. Failed to queue test run to the controller that connects data and diagnostics: ControllerServerAddress. No such host is known

Comment: Setting up controllers and agents can be complex. There are many web pages giving advice. There is too little detail in your question for us to even begin to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
On the test agent update the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file with the controller name and IP address of the test controller. Also to be sure that the performance monitor can be used by the test controller during the test turn on network discovery for the test agent.